# How do I get my for loop to search only for the elements id that I click on?

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

I want to display specific information only from one array but it seems like the for loop is iterating through the other arrays and displaying their names as well

```
const link = document.createElement("a");
  link.href = "#";
  link.id = student.id;
  link.addEventListener("click", function(){openModalCallback(link.id)}, false);
  link.textContent = student.id;
```

this is the function with the for loop in it

```
 function openModalCallback(link, student){
  $('#infoModal').modal('show'); 

    // get student data on click with id as reference
    
   
    for (student of data){
      if( link.id = student.id){
        alert(student.firstN);
      }
      break;
    }
  }
```

Comment: You are passing one parameter to *openModalCallback* but it accepts two. I will also suggest you to add the relevant HTML.

Comment: so should I make it :   link.addEventListener("click", function(){openModalCallback(link.id,student.id)}, false); ?

Comment: I don't know what `student` actually is, but if it's a HTML element, the markup becomes invalid. `id`s are supposed to be unique within the document.

Comment: `link.id = student.id` => `link.id === student.id`

Answer (score 2):

if( link.id **=** student.id){

if you want to check condition, you have to use either == or ===

Answer (score 2):

The function call is passing id as argument but it seems the function itself is using the parameter as the link object, not as an id property.

```
if ( link.id = student.id ) {}
```

In this line `student.id` will be assigned to `link.id` ( if not used in strict mode unless cause an error) then as an implicit conversion if the value of `link.id` was not null, undefined or even zero then the condition was passed as true.
Maybe you want to use comparison operators instead see [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#comparison_operators) I hope this would help.

Answer (score 1):

I can see 2 mistakes in your code

first

```
  link.addEventListener("click", function(){openModalCallback(link.id)}, false);
```

you are not passing link and student object as in you function definition, change this to

```
link.addEventListener("click", function(){openModalCallback(link, student)}, false);
```

second, you are using assignment operator in if condition

```
if( link.id = student.id){
```

change this to logical operator

```
if( link.id == student.id){
```

Hope this solves your issue.

Comment: this did clear up some errors though the for loop still stops and displays only the first entry in the localstorage

Comment: @VinceGarcia remove the break; inside for loop. break will stop the loop.